# Ionic Framework Image Not Loading

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat='item in videos' class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
        <img scr="http://placehold.it/80x80">
</ion-item>
```

I am trying to load an image from placehost.it but it is not loading the image.
I have added

```
<access origin="*" />
```

the above code to my config.xml file. But it is still not loading when I open it on chrome. I have also enabled COR. What shall I do?

Comment: When you open it in chrome, do you see any errors in the console or network tab?

Comment: No, there are no errors. And when I inspect the element the url is corrent.

Comment: In image tag you wrote spell mistake as scr instead of src..please check it even if it will not work mean's reply me

Comment: have you changed the scr to src tag

Comment: in <img tag you spelled mistake it should src but you kept as scr as  <img scr="http://placehold.it/80x80">

Comment: Thanks, That fixed my problem. My bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88372/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-lamia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitelisting the domains using [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) solves the issue.

Add the plugin via CLI:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

and then add the following line of code to your app's config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

and

this meta tag in your index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

EDIT: The reason for this issue:
From Cordova 4.0.0 for Android's update:

> Whitelist functionality is revamped
>
> - You will need to add the new cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to continue using a whitelist
> - Setting a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) is now supported and is the recommended way to whitelist (see details in plugin readme)
> - Network requests are blocked by default without the plugin, so install this plugin even to allow all requests, and even if you are
>     using CSP.
> - This new whitelist is enhanced to be more secure and configurable, but the Legacy whitelist behaviour is still available via a separate
>     plugin (not recommended).
>
> Note: while not strictly part of this release, the latest default app
>   created by cordova-cli will include this plugin by default.

Answer (score 1):

try to use **ng-src** becaue you are importing from website, not locally.

Cheers